# Itext Html2pdf memory management

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using Java Itext Version 7.1.9 and html2pdf 2.1.6. I am using the following code to convert HTML string and add it to pdf. But I'm running out of memory very quickly when trying to add large amounts of data to pdf. When I check the heap dump I see following Itext classes take most of the memory. Most of the memory is taken by some font class. Please suggest on how to reduce memory consumption on adding HTML string to pdf.

[image]

```
private void addHtmlToDocument(String htmlText, Document document) {
        List<IElement> elements;
        try {
            elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(htmlText);
            for (IElement element : elements) {
                if (element instanceof IBlockElement) {
                    document.add((IBlockElement) element);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Unable to add Html elements to pdf document: " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace

```
  at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>()V (OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
  at java.util.HashMap.resize()[Ljava/util/HashMap$Node; (HashMap.java:704)
  at java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; (HashMap.java:663)
  at java.util.HashMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (HashMap.java:612)
  at java.util.HashSet.add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (HashSet.java:220)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.tagging.LayoutTaggingHelper.releaseFinishedHints()V (LayoutTaggingHelper.java:282)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer.updateCurrentArea(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/layout/LayoutResult;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/layout/LayoutArea; (DocumentRenderer.java:99)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.updateCurrentAndInitialArea(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/layout/LayoutResult;)V (RootRenderer.java:463)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/renderer/IRenderer;)V (RootRenderer.java:234)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IElement;)V (RootElement.java:377)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/IPropertyContainer; (RootElement.java:106)
  at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Lcom/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement;)Lcom/itextpdf/layout/Document; (Document.java:160)
  at org.test.service.VRGeneratorImpl.addHtmlToDocument(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/itextpdf/layout/Document;)
```

Comment: Those are not the latest versions. Does the problem reproduce with the latest versions of iText 7 Core and pdfHTML?

Comment: @AlexeySubach  Retried with latest versions of Itext7-core 7.1.12 and html2pdf 2.1.7.  Still out of memory issue occurs.